# uninitialized constant Order::OrderItem with belongs_to in OrderItem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activemodel

I have a code that once i create the order, it will automatically fill up information for the order items (because every order has many items) but i have the error uninitialized constant Order::OrderItem. How do i solve this?

**Model**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  attr_accessible :amount, :currency


  has_many :order_items
end

class OrderItems < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :items, :order_id, :quantity

  belongs_to :order
end
```

**Controller**

```
 def checkout
    @order = Order.new # Create new order
    @order.total = @shopping_cart.total
    @order.sub_total = @shopping_cart.subtotal
    @order.sales_tax = @shopping_cart.taxes

    @shopping_cart.shopping_cart_items.each do |cart_item|
       @orderitems = @order.order_items.build(items: cart_item.item.name, quantity: cart_item.quantity)
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> uninitialized constant Order::OrderItem

The problem is with this line

```
class OrderItems < ActiveRecord::Base
```

`Model class names` supposed to be **`singular`**.Change `OrderItems` to `OrderItem`.And also don't forget to change the **`model file name`** as well.